# TypeScript definition does not match default export

Tags: javascript, typescript, puppeteer, typescript-typings

I'm trying to use Puppeteer with TypeScript, `@types/puppeteer`, and Jest.

Puppeteer uses a default export, and this works as `pptr.test.js`:

```
import pptr from 'puppeteer'

pptr.launch(
  // ... config here
)
```

However, when I install `@types/puppeteer` and rename to `pptr.test.ts`, I get this TS error:

> Module '"/home/jack/Documents/Extensions/messages-example/node_modules/@types/puppeteer/index"' has no default export.

The code does transpile and run in Jest using Babel.

Neither of these work, but do pass TS checks:

```
import { launch } from 'puppeteer'
```

```
import * as pptr from 'puppeteer'
```

Both fail with a TypeError like "... is not a function".

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017",
  }
}
```

Is `@types/puppeteer` wrong? What is the best way to handle a TypeScript situation like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set `esModuleInterop` and `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` under the `compilerOptions` prop in your `tsconfig.json`

You should be able to import it as a default then.

Comment: Tried, tested. Works like a charm!